# LSH and bands for document similarity

Tags: algorithms, data-mining

I have 50 documents and im using LSH+Minhashing Jaccard and i get this results:

- for bands:25 -> false positives: 200
- for bands:10 -> false positives: 80
- for bands:2 -> false positives: 28
- for bands:1 -> false positives: 4

Can anyone explain me why im getting more false positives for bigger number of bands and while decrease bands im getting less false positives?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  1. Can you explain what "bands" are?   Can you describe the scheme in a bit more detail?  I'm familiar with LSH and MinHash, but I'm not entirely sure what precisely "LSH+Minhashing Jaccard" means.  Can you edit the question to elaborate?  2. Have you tried calculating what number of false positives you *expect* to get, based on probability theory?  If so, can you edit the question to show that?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/68376/755, http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/255030/2921.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.